# I renewed my passport and my Algerian visa is on my old passport. Will this create problems with Immigration?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, algeria, passport-renewals

I renewed my passport and my Algerian visa is on my old passport. Will this create problems with Immigration?

Comment: _Most_ countries are okay with having a visa in an old passport, if only the visa _itself_ is still valid. But I don't know positively that Algeria is one of them.

Comment: My close vote is b/c a cogent answer is difficult, absent the added info requested by @pnuts and OP has not been back since the moment the question was posted several months ago.

Comment: @Dorothy Well, two months ago. But I agree, that's plenty.